# Open source projects

Tags: open-source, project

I'm a computer science student and I want to get started contributing with open source projects. Can someone help me? Where do I start? Can you suggest small projects where I can start? (C/C++, java, python)

Also, where big projects like: linux kernel, firefox, mysql, apache... are hosted? (github?) Are they on public repositories where I can start deploying code?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and do a search on their site. Others have already asked this question there, so you're likely to find the answer from a search,

Comment: Well, first *find a project you like*, then *look at the existing code* and the *patch/submit policies*, and decide if you want to (e.g. if it's worth your time) provided patches or other such help. I won't even touch most of the Open Source project code out there as much of it is just trash. Any sizable project has documentation and howto guides and request/bug lists and ... so "ask google".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [article](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/03/12/1728234/how-to-contribute-to-open-source-without-being-a-programming-rock-star) on today's slashdot about just this topic.  The gist is that you should

1. Find a project you are interested in.
2. Start reading their mailing list and issue-tracker.
3. Start reading the code.